# Dropbox menu no longer opens folder or website

Tags: gnome, dropbox, 19.04

Since my upgrade to 19.04, the Dropbox menu in the status bar (top right) does not open the Dropbox folder or the website. In other words, the two upper functions of this menu do not work:

[image: dropbox menu screenshot]

However, Dropbox itself is still working. I can open the folder `~/Dropbox` and the files are synced.

Comment: In syslog I see an error message like this: `Unknown option --no-desktop`. Nautilus no longer accepts this option; `man nautilus` does not give info about this option. A previous version man page shows this: `--no-desktop
              Never manage the desktop  (ignore  the  GSettings  preference).  Deprecated  -  the desktop is managed in a separate binary.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple `grep`-ing for `--no-desktop` does not return results on clean VM with default Ubuntu 19.04 with GNOME Shell.

But we can fix this using non-trivial hack - we will write wrapper for `/usr/bin/nautilus`.
This will be shell script `/usr/local/bin/nautilus` with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
$(echo "/usr/bin/nautilus $@" | sed 's/--no-desktop//')
```

*Note: the script above removes `--no-desktop` argument from argument list and it is quick and dirty hack, better solution may exist*.

Do not forget to make this script executable with

```
sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/nautilus
```

and you will get normally working Dropbox tray icon:

[image: fixed Nautilus Dropbox on Ubuntu 19.04]

---

Also I have an alternative - `caja-dropbox` package - it provides integration of Dropbox into Caja file-manager from [MATE DE](https://mate-desktop.org/).
It works as expected in all Ubuntu versions including 19.04:

[image: caja-dropbox in Ubuntu MATE 19.04]

IMHO it is a time to switch to full-feature `ubuntu-mate-desktop`.